# Derivation for capacitance and inductance formulas for Linkwitz Riley and Butterworth crossovers

Tags: filter, passive-filter

I'm only a high school student but was looking into some aspects of crossover design. In particular, I was learning about this crossover:

[image]

I understand the derivation of the crossover/cutoff frequency in terms of L and C, but I found these formulas for the individual values of `C1`,`C2` and `L1`,`L2`. I would love to know how these are derived. Also, if someone could tell me if/how this derivation would be different for a 2nd Butterworth crossover, that'd be great! If anyone could help I would appreciate it!